# Graphics card crippled after upgrade to 21.04

Tags: graphics, gpu

I have recently performed the upgrade to Ubuntu 21.04.
(The KDE branch, to be exact)
Once I finished, I right away noticed the GPU was running hotter than normal (around 3c more idle) and OBS wasn't working, but I didn't think much of it.

But, now I decided to use a WebGL application, and, even with the latest drivers, I have issues using OBS and WebGL.

Card; NVIDIA GeForce GT 710

Tested Drivers: Nvidia Driver 390, Nvidia Driver 460

Issue Occurred: Immediately after upgrade to 21.04

CPU: Intel I5 @ 3.2GHZ

EDIT: I forgot to mention, but I tried updating both drivers with the issue remaining. I still cannot use OBS (though if i set it to software encoding it works) or WebGL, speaking of, I use Firefox.

Comment: Maybe you're now running Wayland?  Check the options on the login screen, under some gear or pop-down for graphics choices and pick the non-wayland one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The driver to use should be 460 at the time of this writing: https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/172376/en-us (for reference only, do not install from here, all the required drivers are available at the Ubuntu rpeository)

Experimenting with different driver versions without properly deleting all remains of the previous version often results in conflicts.

Using Additional Drivers at all times should prevent the aforementioned problem but generally such "experiments" are strongly discouraged. Install the proper version and don't touch it, the system will automatically install updates when and if needed.

In order to assure the correct and best driver is installed without conflicts please do the following, in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Comment: Trying this now

Comment: This worked and fixed both the OBS and WebGL problems.